# What part of Widget Tree is rebuild when we use "listen:true" in Provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

What part of Widget Tree Gets rebuild when we use `Provider.of(context, listen:true)`

For example:

```
Scaffold
    -- Center
          -- Text(Provider<Name>.of(context, listen:true).getName() )
```

(listen:true)
Whether entire Scafflold will be rebuild or only Text Will be rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs of the Provider :
If [listen] is `true`, later value changes will trigger a new
[State.build] to widgets, and [State.didChangeDependencies] for
[StatefulWidget].

`listen: false` is necessary to be able to call `Provider.of` inside
[State.initState] or the `create` method of providers like so:

State.build triggered meaning that your widget tree will be rebuild.